# Mongo DB query collection by subcollection attribute

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, database

I have:

```
public class Movie : IMongoEntity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}

 public class Actor : IMongoEntity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If i want to retrieve the entire movie collection I do

```
var query = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.FindAllAs<Movie>();
```

No I want to retrieve just the movies that have an actor with a certain name

I've tried something like:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query<Movie>.Where(m => m.Actors.Select(a => a.Name).Any(n => n.Contains(actorName)));

        var exc = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Find(query);
```

But that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var query = Query<Movie>.ElemMatch(m => m.Actors, builder => builder.EQ(actor => actor.Name, actorName));
var exc = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Find(query);
```